# How to represent a superscript slash with Unicode?

Tags: unicode

Is there any way I can write a superscript slash with Unicode?

My aim is to represent rational exponents in a nicer form than `123**(456/789)`.

Comment: PRIME (\u2032) is closest to a superscript '/'.  Although if you have the choice, output in a layout format (tex, html?) depending on your target.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. On general grounds, we can be pretty sure that if such a character existed, it would be in the [Superscripts and Subscripts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf) block (not all superscripts are there, but the odds are that if any superscripts will be added, they will be placed there).

So you need some higher-level protocol, as you usually do, when you need superscripts beyond a fairly limited repertoire. Unicode is about encoding characters, not about layout and mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 43):

Well unicode is full of characters. The meaning is up to its interpretation.

For superscript slash you can use:

- [Canadian Syllabics Final Acute](https://unicode-table.com/en/141F/) 123⁴⁵⁶ᐟ⁷⁸⁹
- [Right Raised Omission Bracket](https://unicode-table.com/en/2E0D/) 123⁴⁵⁶⸍⁷⁸⁹
- [Musical Symbol Repeated Figure-1](https://unicode-table.com/en/1D10D/) 123⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹

For subscript slash you can use:

- [Right Low Paraphrase Bracket](https://unicode-table.com/en/2E1D/) 123₄₅₆⸝₇₈₉

If you have other solutions please comment and I will update my answer.

A helpful site to find special unicode characters: [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/)

Comment: They may LOOK like those characters, but their SEMANTICS is different. So this is more like a hack (with all of its consequences of being semantically confusing) than a solution. But that's the problem with Unicode, and that's a pity that instead of introducing two combining characters that would allow to send ANY other character to the upper or lower index, they decided instead to litter the character table with a bunch of superscript and subscript characters of their own arbitrary choice – a list that will ALWAYS be incomplete.

Comment: Who cares about the semantics of unicode? As if each letter of an alphabet has a clear semantic meaning. The meaning of symbols is propably always context-dependent. They could just add "superscript"/"subscript" as a semantic description to one of the listed symbols and everything would be fine again. My point is: Semantics for symbols are opinion-based.

Comment: Nobody, apparently :q

Answer (score 3):

Assuming http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts is accurate, the answer is no.

Comment: Well, then goulashsoup's answer above clearly shows that Wikipedia article is not really that accurate ;)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the complete official Unicode name list](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt) and making the bold assumption it would have "slash" either in its name or description, there is no such character at this time.