# How to represent fractional power in unicode?

Tags: wpf, unicode

I want to represent a mathematical formula/equations in Unicode for my WPF Application. I am able to represent all sorts of mathematical symbol using only unicode but now one of my equation has a fractional power And I stuck because i am not able to find how to represent the Fraction in power.

```
9 X 3² + 3(8)^2/3
```

How 2/3 will be superscripted ? I want a pure UNICODE solution.

Comment: 3² + (8)^¹/²  what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to represent a superscript slash with Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239848/how-to-represent-a-superscript-slash-with-unicode)

Comment: I think you are trying to get Unicode to do something that it is not designed to do. It is not a layout notation.

Comment: @PhilHibbs Why and How superscripted ' / ' does not fall in the category of character encoding  and why the ' + ', ' - ', ' = ' falls in the category.

Comment: I can't answer why it has those other characters and not the slash. Probably because some earlier character set included them and they didn't want people to lose functionality.

Comment: @PhilHibbs (1) Unicode represents characters in written language, including mathematical notation. (2) Unicode already has "layout" (what you call layput, not what I call layout), like ñ, é, å, ô, œ, etc.

Comment: Accented characters are characters, not layout, but anyway this is not an appropriate forum for discussing the philosophy behind Unicode's design. It doesn't have superscript slashes (although it might have characters that visually resemble them, see below), end of answer. Forget I ever said anything about why.

Answer (score 2):

e.g. `8³ᐟ⁴`

afaict, `ᐟ` is not “semantic”, like `⁺` and `⁻` are, but it looks right.

---

> The Unified Canadian Aboriginal Syllabics and its Extended blocks contain several mostly consonant-only letters to indicate syllable coda called Finals, along with some characters that indicate syllable medial known as Medials: Main block ᐜ ᐝ ᐞ ᐟ ᐠ ᐡ ᐢ ᐣ ᐤ ᐥ ᐦ ᐨ ᐩ ᐪ ᑉ ᑊ ᑋ ᒃ ᒄ ᒡ ᒢ ᒻ ᒼ ᒽ ᒾ ᓐ ᓑ ᓒ ᓪ ᓫ ᔅ ᔆ ᔇ ᔈ ᔉ ᔊ ᔋ ᔥ ᔾ ᔿ ᕐ ᕑ ᕝ ᕪ ᕻ ᕽ ᖅ ᖕ ᖖ ᖟ ᖦ ᖮ ᗮ ᘁ ᙆ ᙇ ᙚ ᙾ ᙿ, Extended block ᣔ ᣕ ᣖ ᣗ ᣘ ᣙ ᣚ ᣛ ᣜ ᣝ ᣞ ᣟ ᣳ ᣴ ᣵ. Additionally, there are two Finals, a Medial, and two punctuations written as raised characters in the main block: ᐀ ᐧ ᕀ ᕁ ᕯ.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Other_superscript_and_subscript_characters

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts_(Unicode_block)#Block